# Denoting the antiderivative of velocity

Tags: kinematics, notation, integration, calculus

With simple Newtonian laws (and in a specific context), I learned that the speed $\vec{v}$ of an object is the derivative of the corresponding position vector $\vec{OM}$. So that means that 
$$\vec{v}(t)=\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{OM}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}.$$

So, if we only have the speed of an object, we need to calculate the primitive of $\vec{v}$ to find the corresponding $\vec{OM}$ vector.

But how can I write it with math symbols? Many people use the integral notation without any domain specified (just the $\int{}$ symbol and I think there isn't any domain specified because it's a notation?) but it's not exactly the same as a primitive right? Or may be I just don't know the correct way for writing primitives.

I heard about the $\sideset{^a_b}{}{\left[\vec{v}\right]}$ notation, but I'm not sure about what it means and how to use it.

Comment: What do you mean by a “ primitive”?

Comment: I'm not really sure if that is the right word to use in english... I also found "antiderivative"? May be that's more conventional?

Comment: “Antiderivative” or “integral” are both used. Position is the integral of velocity over time: $$\mathbf{r}(t_2)-\mathbf{r}(t_1)=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\mathbf{v}(t)dt.$$

Comment: No, the integral is defined by two antiderivatives. For example,
$\int^b_af(x)dx=[F(x)]_a^b=F(b)-F(a)$ with F(x) the antiderivative function of f.
My questions are : firstly, why on physics notations isn't there any a and b and so, should we use the $\int^b_af(x)dx$ or the $[F(x)]_a^b$ notation?

Comment: Your antiderivative $F$ is just the position $r$. Velocity is the derivative of pisition, so position is the antidetivative of velocity. There *are* $a$ and $b$... they are $t_1$ and $t_2$. You are integrating over time, from a starting time to an ending time.

Comment: Primitive is also used in English, it is an acceptable term to denote the antiderivative of a function

Comment: @G.Smith "Primitive" or "primitive function" are acceptable English terms for the antiderivative. But I suppose they're more likely to be found in older literature, and they're perhaps more common in Britain & Commonwealth countries.

Comment: I didn't change it in the edit, but $`` \vec{v} "$ is "_velocity_", while $`` v "$ is "_speed_".  It's the inclusion of direction that distinguishes velocity from speed.

Comment: As for "_primitive_", it's a general description applicable to anything that's not describable as being composed in some context.  We don't discuss primitives much in the context of physics because usually physics takes a hand-waving approach to the topic, though when physics does care for the topic, we tend to use the term "_fundamental_" instead, e.g. as in "_fundamental particles_", which could also be called "_primitive particles_" if it weren't for breaking the idiom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to write it is

$$\mathbf{r}(t_2)-\mathbf{r}(t_1)=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\mathbf{v}(t)dt.$$

This is the integrated version of

$$\mathbf{v}(t)=\frac{d\mathbf{r}(t)}{dt}.$$

Comment: And when we just write $\vec{r}(t)=\int\vec{v}(t)dt$, what $t1$ and $t2$ do we use?

Comment: Any you want. If you know some initial position, and the velocity as a function of time, you can find the position at any later time.

Comment: Have you learned about definite vs. indefinite integrals? When you don’t have limits, it is an indefinite integral. (Just giving the antiderivative $F$.) When you have limits, you take the difference of the antiderivative at these limits.

Comment: Not at all, I think that's the problem!

Answer (score 4):

Let $\vec{v}$ be te velocity vector, and $\vec{r}$ the position vector.

Indeed, you are right, it is true that

$$  \vec{v}=\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}$$

But, you should be aware of one thing: all derivatives imply some **loss of information**, because you lose track of the constants. See:

- The derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$.
- The derivative of $x^2+3$ is also $2x$.
- In general $x^2+\mathrm{constant}$ yields $2x$.

This is a loss of information. Now, if you want to go "backwards", you have many possibilities. IF someone tells you that "the derivative is $2x$, there is no way you know what the constant was. That's why it is called "indefinite integral".

So, when you want to get position starting from its derivative (velocity), **you need one more thing**.

That extra data is called **Boundary conditions**. IT means that you need to know an extra equation, so that you can solve all the unknowns. This extra information is usually "at a certain time, the position is this one". That is enough to solve anything.

That said, you've got two options now.

A) DEFINITE INTEGRAL.

As the others have pointed out, if $\vec{v}=d\vec{r}/dt$, then

$$  \Delta\vec{r}=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \vec{v}\cdot dt $$

which means

$$  \vec{r}_{t_2}-\vec{r}_{t_1}=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} v\cdot dt $$

Check that, if you want the new position, $\vec{r}_{t_2}$, you'd need $\vec{r}_{t_1}$, the boundary condition.

*Example: 1D constant velocity*

$r_2-r_1=v\cdot \Delta t$.

It is the usual equation:  $r=r_0+vt$

---

B) INDEFINITE INTEGRAL + Boundary conditions

You can also solve

$$  \vec{r}=\int \vec{v}\cdot dt $$

For a 1D constant velocity, you will get

$r=v\cdot t + \mathrm{constant}$

And now you must use the extra data to complete the information.

For $t=0$, $r=r_0$.

Then, substituting in the equation:    $r_0=v\cdot0+\mathrm{constant} \ \Rightarrow  \mathrm{constant}=r_0$

So you get the same result: $r=r_0+vt$.

**Both methods are equivalent**.